# Visual slideshow with concrete5 not working right

Tags: jquery, concrete5

Trying to get a slider to work right on my website at: http://www.thebrazilianlanguage.com". The way it should look is referenced here: http://www.thebrazilianlanguage.com/visual-slideshow-template.htm (notice all thumbnails display and are positioned closer to one another?). I believe there may be a conflict with jquery or other java code on the page, but I know nothing about javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of extraneous margin and padding on the `li`s and even the `ul` in your stylesheets, specifically iGotStyle.css lines 2089 and 2101 and slideshow.css line 112. Start with those.